# cool vs cold (which can be used to express the temperature)

Tags: word-choice, grammar, grammaticality

which word can we use to say that temperature ?

example 1 - its too **cool** over here,

example 2 - its too **cold** over here,

i have heard that cold means too much cool but would like to know whether is correct or not. tnx

Comment: i think example 1 is wrong. it's too cold over here is right.
But u use `cool` as: It will be a cool Morning.

Comment: If it is too cool, then it is very trendy to be over here

Comment: If we're talking about an air conditioner in a room, _It's too cool over here_ is perfectly fine. But you hafta have a reason to say _too **cool**_ specifically, because _too cool_ normally means _uncomfortably cold_ and _too cold_ will work for that in almost all of the same circumstances. Note: this is not just about _cool_ and _cold_; the _too_ is a negative and forms phrases with different syntax. Whenever there's a negative in an English sentence you're having trouble with, try it without the negative; and contrariwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that using the word "too" makes a big difference in this sentence. It's perfectly acceptable to my ear to say "It's too cool over here" in a context in which warmth is expected. In this case, I might also use the phrase "It's cold over here" to mean the same thing as "too cool" because it is supposed to be warm or hot. "It's too cold over here" would be most acceptable if I expected it to be cool.

Basically, I think English speakers would consider air temperature "cool" to be in the 60s Fahrenheit, and "cold" to be closer to 40F. For liquids (for which internal body temperature is usually the basis for comparison, such as hot drinks or a swimming pool), I would think 80s for "cool" (e.g. below body temp), and cold starting in the low 70sF. Of course, if you're thinking of cold drinks, I would consider a soda "warm" if it was 70F.

Once you use the word "too," however, you are now talking more about personal perception than actual temperature.

You might also consider using the word "chilly," which generally connotes "uncomfortably cool," as opposed to "uncomfortably cold." I don't think of "chilly" as tied specifically to a temperature, more to a personal preference and contrast with what is expected or preferred.

Answer (score 1):

**Both can refer to temperature.**

"Too cool" usually implies that the temperature is too low, relatively. It does not necessarily imply that it feels cold. It can actually still be referring to something that is quite warm, just *not warm enough* for some purpose.

> *It is too cool in the summer at this latitude for oranges to grow.*
>
> *The reaction was too cool to produce the correct yield.*
>
> *It is too cool in here for the paint to dry properly.*

"Too cold" usually implies feelings of discomfort from cold, often indicating that the discomfort makes certain actions inappropriate.

> *It is too cold outside to wear short sleeves.*
>
> *It is too cold in here to think.*
>
> *Today is too cold to play soccer.*

Both can also refer to attitudes of people. "Too cool" can mean snobbish or indifferent, and "too cold" can mean excessively unwelcoming.